# Tweepy quoted status "Status has no attribute quoted_status"

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm using python and calling an api request. Not all the tweets have quoted_status field since not all of them are quoted. How can I overcome the error

```
AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'quoted_status'
```

and print for example 'null' if the quoted_status is not available?

I'm working in a loop, my actual code is this:

```
for status in timeline:
    print status.quoted_status
```

I tried also with except but with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether the object has the attribute with `hasattr` keyword.

```
for status in timeline:
    if hasattr(status, 'quoted_status'):
        print (status.quoted_status)
    else:
        print ("null")
```

***hasattr(object, name)***

> The arguments are an object and a string. The result is True if the
>   string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, False if not.
>   (This is implemented by calling getattr(object, name) and seeing
>   whether it raises an exception or not.)